# Best Formatting for Nested Nods JS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nested

I have an application I am writing using Node JS and was wondering what the best formatting for nested code is. For example:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var pg = require('pg');
var client = new pg.Client();
var config1 = {
  REMOVED
};
var pool1 = new pg.Pool(config1);
var config2 = {
  REMOVED
};
var pool2 = new pg.Pool(config2);
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  pool1.connect(function(err, client1, done) {
    pool2.connect(function(err, client2, done) {
      client1.query("FIRST QUERY", [], function(err, result) {
        client1.query("SECOND QUERY", [], function(err, result) {
          client2.query("THIRD QUERY", [], function(err, result) {


          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Each query is dependent on the results of the previous query and must be done in that order.

I still have another 2/3 queries to go. Is the code example the best way of formatting this? Or is there another better way?

Thanks,

Comment: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) were pretty much built for this purpose.

Comment: There is [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy when using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*initialization options*/);
var db = pgp(config); // config is a string or object

db.task(t => {
    return t.query('FIRST QUERY', [params])
        .then(data => {
            return t.query('SECOND QUERY', [params]);
        })
        .then(data => {
            return t.query('THIRD QUERY', [params]);
        })
})
    .then(data => {
        // SUCCESS
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // FAILED
    });
```

And if you need to use a transaction, then you simply replace method [task](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.task) with [tx](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.tx).